# How to install while keeping extra Windows drives

Tags: windows, partitioning

I have genuine Windows 7 Home Premium in my HP laptop. A few days back it didn't accept my admin password. Now I want to load my machine with Ubuntu. The following is my partition details:

```
C: // has windows

D: // recovery disk
E: and F: // data
```

I don't want to delete the `E:\` and `F:\` drives.

Is there a way I can load Ubuntu into my machine? I don't mind giving up Windows 7.

```
Partition          filesys       label      size       used       unused         flag
/dev/sda1           ntfs         SYStem     992.5kb      -           -           
/dev/sda2           ntfs                    199.00mb     -           -           boot
/dev/sda3           ntfs         Stud      228.2gb     90.19gb    138.01gb
/dev/sda4           ntfs         cram      237.37gb    53.66gb    183.7gb
unallocated       unallocated                   1mb
```

Comment: you can easily boot ubuntu with the desktop CD, it will run live without installing it. If you like you may install ubuntu. Just be sure to read the installation guide and understand how linux identifies partition.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! If you are able to boot your laptop from an Ubuntu LiveCD, can you please start up the GParted utility and provide a detailed list of what partitions it sees and how they're labeled? This would greatly help us in answering your question!

Comment: Sure. I am able to run the live os. but when i attempt to install through the wizard, when it comes to partition screen, the partition is named as follows:
/dev
/dev/sda and so on. Anyways, I'll check the partitioning through the GParted as well. Thanks for your concern.

Answer (score 1):

why don't you go through the [UBUNTU installation guide](http://ubuntumanual.org/guides/435/how-to-install-ubuntu-11-10-oneric-ocelot-an-ubuntu-installation-guide). It will surly help you

Comment: I have ubuntu 10.10. while installing i encountered after selecting the partition, "no root directory".. what does that mean?

Comment: while selecting the partition =you will get a popup window right there in the last you will get a drop down menu there select "/" for the partition you want to install the ubuntu.